# Explain Plan output in Oracle

Tags: oracle, formatting, sql-execution-plan

I'm not expert on Oracle just started working around. When I execute following queries it gives me output in `|`(pipeline) format. I want `EXPLAIN PLAN` output in `tabluar` or `json` or `xml`, etc... Is it possible?

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM user_master;
SELECT plan_table_output FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table'));

Output:

    Plan hash value: 3060894046

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation         | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |             |     1 |    94 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| USER_MASTER |     1 |    94 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: When you use an IDE like TOAD they offers you several display options for explain plans. Maybe that's an option for you.

Comment: What happens if you issue "SET MARKUP ON" in sqlplus before running EXPLAIN PALN? Normally this renders query results as HTML, so might be worth a try.

Comment: You're probably best off getting used to the text format.  It has most of the useful information and is frequently used in printed sources.  When people post graphical representations of the explain plan on here they usually leave out vital information, or it makes it more difficult to compare plans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it in tabular format if you access the `PLAN_TABLE` directly:

```
select plan_id,
       operation,
       options,
       cost,
       cpu_cost,
       io_cost,
       temp_space,
       access_predicates,
       bytes,
       object_name,
       object_alias,
       optimizer,
       object_type
from plan_table
start with parent_id is null
connect by prior id = parent_id;
```

As the plan_table can contain different plans, it's probably better to use an explicit statement id:

```
explain plan 
  set statement_id = 'foo'
for
select ...;
```

and then use that in the select on the  plan_table:

```
select ....
from plan_table
start with parent_id is null and statement_id = 'foo'
connect by prior id = parent_id;
```

To get this as XML you can use:

```
select dbms_xplan.display_plan(type => 'xml')
FROM dual
```